# Creating user accounts javascript and API's

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, user-accounts

I recently started learning about API's and how to get and post data to an API.

So for example I have a sign up form on my site:

```
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
        <p>Name: <input ng-model="person.name"></p>
        <p>Password: <input ng-model="person.password"></p>
        <p><button>Add</button></p>
        </form>
```

Which when submitted Posts data to a JSON API.

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('PeopleController', function ($scope, $http) {

  var url = 'https://something.com/users.json';

  $http.get(url).success(function(a) {
    console.log(a);
    $scope.people = a;
  });

  $scope.submit = function() {
    $http.post(url, $scope.person)
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
   });

    }});
```

The API looks like this:

```
   {
      "people" : [
    {"name": "Charles Babbage", "password": abc1791},
    {"name": "Tim Berners-Lee", "password": cde1955},
    {"name": "George Boole", "password": efg1815}
    ]
  }
```

Now I am aware Im missing a lot of stuff like a database such as mongoDB and few other things and this is example is too simple.

But how do I use this information from my API to create user accounts. So if Charles Babbage Signs-in he sees his personal (very basic) profile where he can edit is name and password and then signs out. I am aware I am missing key things such as Authentication and maybe even sessions but I want to take this step by step.

I thank you in advance for any help or advice.

Regards,

Comment: I really think this question is too vague.  You're missing a lot of things.   It would be helpful to me if you were to break this problem down into small sub-questions and ask them one by one.   Is this realted to how users are created on the back-end?  Is it about sending the data from the client to the server?  Is it about getting the form data into the controller?  I'm not even sure if your Add button does anything.  It doesn't look like it connected to anything.

Comment: @zumalifeguard Thank you for the reply. Okay I'll break down the question: Question 1: How users created on the back-end and then are given their own personal accounts on the front-end. Does this question help you or should I break it down more. Apologies for asking vague questions but because I have never done this before I don't know what question to ask. If this question is also too vague can you explain how would you create this functionality. Again apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In order for someone to help you with this question, you have to explain more about what mechanism will be used to create users on the back-end, independent of the client-side technology.   The only thing back-end related you indicated here is "Web-Api", and from that I assume you're asp.net.   Are you talking about the role/membership system in asp.net?   Have you looked at those APIs?   I'm not the one who will answer that because I haven't worked with it a lot.   But maybe you can point to the specific technology that you're going to be using.